# How do you specify the starting position using the command line?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

in this my .bat file

```
@echo off

    schtasks  /create /tn "FTP_UPload" /tr "C:\save_excel\test.bat" /sc daily /st 19:49
```

How to add start-in option commend line modify?

Comment: `schtasks /Create /?` from a command prompt shows you what you can change. I don't see *start-in* among the options there.

Comment: Pass the directory as an argument to `test.bat` and modify the batch to do a `pushd "%~1"` first.

Comment: I often use `%~dp0` in batch files to reference the folder where the batch file is.